# Vue Transition Not Affecting Each Element

Tags: html, sass, css-transitions, vue.js

I have a container with two elements that I would like to toggle with a click.

I'd like to have the visible element slide out while the new element slides in, but the transition only affects the first child (i.e. logo) while the second child (i.e. version) does a simple show/hide. Switching the order of the children doesn't help.

**Markup in component.vue**

```
<div class="brand-container" @click="toggleLogoBox">
  <div class="logo" v-show="logoVisible" transition="slide">
    <img src="../assets/images/logo.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="version" v-show="versionVisible" transition="slide">
    <div class="label">Motor Club</div>
    <div class="number">{{ version }}</div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- brand-container -->
```

**Logic in component.vue**

```
methods: {
  toggleLogoBox: function () {
    this.logoVisible = !this.logoVisible;
    this.versionVisible = !this.versionVisible;
  },
  // ...
```

**Transition**

```
.slide-transition {
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.1,.25,1);
}

.slide-enter {
  transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-leave {
  transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you leave out the **JS** part of the code?

Comment: I don't think my logic adds anything, but I've included it if it helps. `Vue.js` is what provides the transition.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I've recreated exactly what you wanted, *(I'm 99% sure i didn't :D)*. [VueTransitionRecreation](http://jsbin.com/cegemujime/edit?html,css,js,output). But there seem to be no issues with transitions.

Comment: Ahh! I had forgotten to add `position: absolute;` to the elements inside the container, so as the transitions were applied, they weren't always visible because of `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was not an issue of transitions, but of the child elements not having the `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` properties, so that the transitions on each element could be seen from beginning to end.